# Is putting form fields inside label tags a good or bad idea?

Tags: html, forms, dom, label, standards

I notice this trend in a lot of frameworks, auto-generated code (Zend) and layout templates. The approach I'm talking about is such:

```
<label for="someField">
    <input id="someField" name="someName" />
</label>
```

What are the pros and cons of this approach vs. the regular one, and why do people tend to take this approach at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be fine judging by **[W3C standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)** in both HTML4.01 and HTML5:

**HTML4:**

> "To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control
>   element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. In this
>   case, the LABEL may only contain one control element. The label itself
>   may be positioned before or after the associated control."

In this example, we implicitly associate a labels with a text input control:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
  <p>
    <label>
      First Name
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

It is still fine as of **HTML5:**

> "The label element represents a caption in a user interface. The
>   caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the
>   label element's labeled control, either using the for attribute, or by
>   putting the form control inside the label element itself. - [**W3C.**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#labeled-control)

Comment: Ahh, so the purpose is avoiding having to declare "for" on a label tag. Thanks!

Comment: You also have to have a `id` on the form field if you use a `for`

Comment: It's fine by W3C from the past century, you quoted a [recommendation from 1999](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/).

Comment: @n.1 Your comment makes zero sense. It was fine back in 1999, and it is still fine as of 2013.

Comment: Yes, if you still use HTML 4.01. Is it also true with HTML5? (I'm thinking of people's opinions, not validation). Is putting an `<input>` in a `<label>` is a good practice nowadays?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, it's [still valid in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-label-element).

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the above link, explaining that it is still valid in the current recommendations, so I will be able to remove my downvote.